# Limit of a function w

Tags: functions

If $f(x, y)$ is a continus function, defined in whole  $\mathbb R^2$, then the limit

$$\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow(2,2)}f(x, y)(x-1)(y-2) $$

The solution is $0$, but how? A very elaborative explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider each of the three factors separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2$ so in particular on $(2,2)$ then
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}f(x,y)=f(2,2)\to\text{finite value}$$
so

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}f(x,y)(x-1)(y-2)=f(2,2)\times(2-1)\times(2-2)=0$$

Comment: awesome explenation

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If the limits

$$l_1=\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} f_1(x,y)\\
l_2=\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} f_2(x,y)$$

Then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (x_0,y_0)} f_1(x,y)\cdot f_2(x,y) = l_1\cdot l_2$$

In your case, you only need to select the correct $f_1$ and $f_2$. The best will be such that one of $l_1,l_2$ is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The functions $f(x,y)$, $(x-1)$, $(y-2)$ are all continuous, so their product is continuous as well. A property that makes continuous functions nice is that $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (a,b)} g(x,y) = g(a,b) $$ Applying this fact to your limit, you can plug in the values that $x$ and $y$ approach into your function, which evaluates to $f(2,2)(2-1)(2-2) = 0$.